# Efficiently read flattened file in C

Tags: c, performance, file, io

I'm trying to read a large file that has one float per line in C. For this, I put together the code below. It works fine when testing on small data. However, when reading 600 million numbers this way, it is very slow. Any ideas for how I can speed it up? I'm generating the raw file via python, so re-formatting the data (to have multiple numbers in a line separated by commas for example) is also an option. Any insight into why this method is so slow would be greatly appreciated.

```
void read_file(float *W)
{
   FILE *fp;

   int i = 0;

// In this file, one row should contain only one NUMBER!!
// So flatten the matrix.
   if (fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Documents\\GitHub\\base\\numerical\\c\\ReadFile1\\Debug\\data.txt", "r")) {
      while (fscanf(fp, "%f", &W[i]) != EOF) {
         ++i;
      }
      fclose(fp);
   }

   fclose(fp);

   scanf("%d",&i);    
}
```

Comment: Found this article, it may of some help: https://github.com/alexflint/fscanf-speed

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it might be useful.

Comment: Since you control the file generation, why not write it as binary floats so no string parsing is needed?  You can then get the array count as (file size / sizeof(float)) and read it all at once.

Comment: Have you profiled the application? fscanf is likely the cause, but with a matrix that large you could be encroaching on swap space.

Comment: @DaveS - ok, I'll need to look into how to do that. Do you happen to have a sample in C for reading the binary floats by any chance?

Comment: @Rain - sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie. What is "swamp space"?

Comment: They meant "swap space."  For reading binary, malloc the float array then treat it as an unsigned char ("byte") buffer and do bulk reads up to the file size.  There's no reason to read in tiny 4-byte chunks.  This assumes the byte order ("endian-ness") is the same for the CPUs running the Pyhton and C.

Comment: Swap space, or a page file on Windows, is an allocation of main storage (HDD/SSD) used when you exceed available RAM. Reading and synchronizing writes to swap mem is slow, since you have to wait for main storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem years ago. The solution was to replace `fscanf` with `fgets` and `strtod`. This gave much more than a 10-fold improvement, if I recall correctly.

So your loop:

```
  while (fscanf(fp, "%f", &W[i]) != EOF) {
     ++i;
  }
```

should look something like:

```
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
     W[i++] = strtod(buf, 0);
  }
```

---

**Edit:** Error checking is always a good idea. So adding this in, the simple two-liner grows to about ten lines:

```
  char buf[80];
  errno = 0;
  while (!errno && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
      W[i++] = strtod(buf, 0);
  }
  if (errno) { // Maybe ERANGE or EINVAL from strtod, or a read error like EINTR
      int save = errno;
      printf("errno=%d reading line %d\n", save, i); // or perror()
      exit(1);
  }
```

---

**Edit 2:** Regarding error checking, the input file could easily contain text such as `nan` or `inf`, perhaps from some upstream bug. But `strtod` and `fscanf` are perfectly happy to parse these. And this could cause mysterious problems in *your* code.

But it is easy enough to check. Add the code:

```
  int bad = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      bad += !isnormal(W[j]); // check for nan, inf, etc.
  if (bad) {
     // ... handle error
  }
```

Putting this in a separate, simple, loop makes it easier for the compiler to optimize (in theory), especially if you use something like `#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")`.

Comment: Thanks you! Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Consider using setvbuf to make the input buffer large.

Comment: @Joseph.   That is not the case. If someone says their program is running slow and asks why, the answer is almost always "IO".  Putting a large buffer on your file will reduce the number of physical reads to the disk, and is very likely to speed up your program.  My rule of thumb is to treat every IO the same as spending a $100 bill.  The cost is about the same whether you get 15 bytes of 15000 bytes.

Comment: @EvilTeach Yes, you are correct, and my comment was nonsensical. Probably at least a megabyte is called for here rather than the default of about 4K.  So one would add `setvbuf(fp, 0, _IOFBF, 1048576);`.

Comment: **Edit:** There may also be a further speed improvement `strtod` is replaced with `strtodf`.

Comment: I have a library that does that grunt work it for me in 64k chunks.  Most of the time that is "Fast Enough."  Try a bunch of sizes and pick one that works ok, then stop

Comment: Worked great.. wonder why anyone uses fscanf which was giving me all kinds of problems.

Comment: @RohitPandey: What sort of speed-up did you get?

Comment: About 6x. Also, fscanf was somehow reading the same data after about 380 million rows (was fine before that but printing out the same number after that index even though the file had different ones upto 600 million). Your method not only sped things up, but read the data correctly, printing all 600 million numbers correctly.

Comment: Buffer overflows are going to be so much fun with `fgets`. Aren't they? :)

Comment: @RohitPandey: It sounds like `fscanf` failed at the 32-bit boundary of 4 gigabytes, if each row had a 11-digit number.

Comment: @Jeseph each row was 4-5 digits, but it failed somewhere between 380 million and 390 million. So, fscanf has this 4 GB limitation but fgets doesn't?

Comment: I don't really know. But see for example [Reading a large file using C (greater than 4GB) using read function, causing problems](//stackoverflow.com/q/11790822). Maybe you are using an older library?

Comment: @ytpillai: No, because `fgets` is designed better than `gets`.  `fgets` actually can be told the size of the buffer so it doesn't overflow (and Joseph's code does pass the buffer size)

Comment: @BenVoigt See [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664272/causing-a-buffer-overflow-with-fgets). Quite possible that the OS is rescuing you from disaster, but fgets is still unsafe.

Comment: @ytpillai: Well if you pass illegal arguments to your functions your program will crash.  No surprise there.  `fgets` is as safe as any other function.  Functions are considered to be "unsafe" if they can be exploited by external data.  `fgets` can't, because even if a line is larger than the buffer, `fgets` only reads the number of bytes you told it you made space for.

Answer (score 4):

(Comment: This is my second answer.) I see the OP asked in a comment:

> Do you happen to have a sample in C for reading the binary floats by any chance?

A binary version would blow any ascii version out-of-the-water. And is shorter.

Here the OP's function signature has been changed to include the maximum number of floats in the return `W`, and to return the number actually read from the file.

```
size_t read_file(float *W, size_t maxlen)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Documents\\GitHub\\base\\numerical\\c\\ReadFile1\\Debug\\data.txt", "r");
    return fp ? fread(W, sizeof(float), maxlen, fp) : 0;
}
```

Or for something *even* faster, you could use `mmap`... . But this is not available on Windows.

---

**Added:** However, unbuffered I/O is would perhaps be faster. The following function uses a single `malloc` and a single unbuffered `read` to copy a file to the heap. (NB: not yet tested on large files; may need `open64`.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>  

void *readFileToHeap(const char *file, int *len) {
   void *retval = 0;
   ssize_t cnt;
   struct stat st;
   const int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY, 0);
   if (fd < 0)
      return printf("Cannot open %s\n", file), (void *)0;
   if (fstat(fd, &st))
      return perror("fstat()"), close(fd), (void *)0;
   if (!(retval = malloc(st.st_size)))
      return perror("malloc()"), close(fd), (void *)0;
   cnt = read(fd, retval, st.st_size);
   close(fd); // not the best: could clobber errno
   if (cnt < 0)
      return perror("read()"), free(retval), (void *)0;
   if (cnt != st.st_size)
      return printf("Partial read %d\n", cnt), free(retval), (void *)0;
   *len = cnt;
   return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the awesome answers, really saved me :)

Comment: Note that [on Linux, a single `read()` operation can read at most a bit under 2GB of data](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b08fc5277aaa1d8ea15470d38bf36f19dfb0e125/fs/read_write.c#L448), so you're going to have to handle partial read results for large files on Linux.  You can also try `O_DIRECT` to bypass the page cache for even better performance.  And note that *really* fast high-end storage systems can deliver data faster than the kernel can create physical-to-virtual mappings, potentially causing IO stalls/redos with direct IO. So you may have to `memset()` the buffer first.

Comment: *may need `open64`*  Not for this use case.  If you *need* `open64()`, you're running a 32-bit process and can't fit the file into memory anyway. Just run a 64-bit process.